# My system is able to read CDs but not DVDs

Tags: windows-7, drivers, dvd, compact-disc, disc

My laptop(running on windows 7) is able to read CDs but not DVDs. When I insert a DVD it tries it's best to read it i.e.. it makes lot of noise, shows a CD icon near the cursor and shows progress bar loading forever on the explorer, but never reads it.
I tried reinstalling the DVD driver(MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8D1 ATA Device), but that didn't help.
I also used a program developed by Microsoft called "Fix It" to troubleshoot DVD driver errors, but that didn't help.
I remember that I had disabled auto-play a few months back, so now I have enabled it  to check if that was causing the errors, but no use, still the problem is persisting.
I also looked into •HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE •SYSTEM •CurrentControlSet •Control •Class •{4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318} and did not find upper and lower filters
When a DVD is loaded, I double clicked on DVD/CD RW drive in My Computer, the DVD R/RW ejects and says "Insert a disc, Please insert a Disk to Drive F:"

What can I do now?

Comment: May be a duplicate, I read that post before but I did not find any solution to my problem there.

Comment: Anyways, I found the solution. My disc reading lens had been clogged with dirt, I used a lint-free cloth to clean it and now it works fine. {Problem Solved}

Comment: Just because you didn't find a solution when you looked, doesn't make your *question* any different. Check out [bounties](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) in the help section for more information. Anyhow, I posted my response to that duplicate, and even edited it to remind people to try the basics, like cleaning the drive/disks of dust. ;)